# What did Numenorean swords / Andúril look like?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, weapon

I was wondering what Andúril looks like, and I know that distinctive look John Howe gives it, with the holes on the ends.

[image: Anduril]

As far as I remember, John Howe wrote in his site that all Numenorean swords look like that, though it may have been a joke.
I want to know what Numenorean (and Gondorian) swords look like. They do seem to have a distinctive look, since in FOTR: "The Ring Goes South", Boromir's sword is described as being

> a long sword, in fashion like Andúril but of less lineage

Comment: Anduril is actually a Dwarvish sword; in it's pre-broken incarnation as Narsil it was forged by Telchar of Nogrod, who was also responsible for the knife used by Beren to cut a Silmaril from Morgoth's crown and for Turin's Dragon Helm.  See the Two Towers chapter King of the Golden Hall: "Telchar first wrought it in the deeps of time."  More info at http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/n/narsil.html

Comment: @mho1 Thanks, I'd to +100 for that! By the way, have a look at the tolkien chat room.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't deserve rep because it doesn't answer your question; it's just an interesting observation.

Comment: @mh01 Well, it *did* save me from finding out information on Numenorean swords, and then (falsely) transfer that to Narsil/Anduril. Did you peep in the chat room?

Comment: @mh01 Of course, an other question is if Narsil was forged in *Dwarvish* style.

Comment: Interesting observation: Narsil="Anar/Ithil": "*it shone with the light of the sun and of the moon*"; Minas Anor/Minas Ithil; Anórien/Ithilien; Anárion/Isildur - those Numenoreans sure liked their sun and moon!

Comment: @JimmyShelter nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The sword of Elendil was forged anew by Elvish smiths, and on its blade was traced a device of seven stars set between the crescent Moon and the rayed Sun, and about them was written many runes; for Aragorn, son of Arathorn was going to war upon the marches of Mordor. Very bright was that sword when it was made whole again; the light of the sun shone redly in it, and the light of the moon shone cold, and its edge was hard and keen.

from *The Fellowship of the Ring*, The Ring Goes South. There's the best description of it you're gonna get! Enjoy!

Comment: That's a great find, but can you edit some citations into it? I think it's a helpful partial answer, but still doesn't answer the OP since the elves re-forged Anduril but were not the original forgers, who were dwarves.

Comment: There ya go, I added some citations but I shouldn't add the page numbers since it's different in every book/format. as far as your second point goes, you can assume it's appearance is still exactly the same as before when it was Anduril. As far as the appearance of other weapons go, I doubt any weapons of the Third Age looked half as beautiful as Anduril/Narsil which was forged by the First Age Dwarf Telchar. Hope that helped a bit!

Comment: I already saw that, should have put it in the question. . .

Comment: "Reforging" a sword is a weird description to be honest. If a sword is to have any strength you would have to completely melt it down and add more steel (or whatever Middle Earth swords are made of) to compensate for that which will be removed in the manufacturing process. Good swords get part of their strength from cooling as a complete object, and simply joining the shards of a broken sword would be likely to leave it incredibly weak.

Comment: @vogomatix: You're forgetting that: 1. Elven smithy is unlike that of Humans and 2. It's MAAAAAGIIIIC...

Comment: Not at all - whilst magic plays a part, Tolkien presented the Elves and Dwarves as being masters of the art, and this is what mastery of the art tells you to do. When Tolkien wrote, metallurgy and alloy knowledge was quite low, but he would have based his knowledge on what was known of swordmaking by vikings etc. We're now incredibly good at it, mainly because of jet aircraft, but also because we now understand how some ancient techniques worked and as a result we're able to refine those practices.

Comment: additionally, it is said in Ch3 "The Ring Goes South" that Boromir "had a long sword, in fashion like Andruil but of less lineage" so that could be taken to mean that it isn't wildly divergent from other swords of the period

Answer (score 2):

Tolkien would probably have in mind Anglo-Saxon/Viking swords as the weapon of choice, as the poetry and mythology of Middle Earth has a basis in his studies in that area. I would also go for that style in preference to a sword of a later era which would emphasise thrusting more (e.g. [Estoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estoc)). The limited description of the fights imply a cutting style of use.

I would suggest that you look at Viking pattern-welded swords as the basis, with something like the sword of Elendil being a little like an [+VLFBERH+T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulfberht) sword in quality and characteristics.

I would also go for a high quality but functional look instead of being very ornate. Killing people and orcs is a serious business and unnecessary adornment could affect your chances in a fight.